# Flutter: How Do I Set a Container's Width to a Calculated Value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that gets a decimal as a property, and I want to use that decimal to calculate the width of a `Container`. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double percent;
  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.percent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: percent * double.infinity, //<-- Here
      height: 5,
    );
  }
}
```

The result of `percent * double.infinity` never amounts to more than a few pixels. I have also tried hard-coding it to something like:

```dart
width: percent * 100, //<-- Here
```

But that doesn't render more than a few pixels either. My assumption is that the `Container` isn't getting an actual width. I've tried making this a `StatefulWidget` and setting the width value in `initState()` but that doesn't seem to help either:

```dart
var width = 5.0;
@override
void initState() {
  width = widget.airport.percent ?? 0.0 * 100.0;
  super.initState();
}
```

How can I calculate a `width` value on-the-fly like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `LayoutBuilder` for your widget: it will give you context and BoxConstraints as arguments and you can get the max width available for the widget in that `BoxConstraints` by using: `constraints.maxWidth` or height using `constraints.maxHeight`

here is a sample code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double percent;
  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.percent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (ctx, constraints){
        return Cointainer(
         width: percent * constraints.maxWidth, 
         height: 5, // also you can use constraints.maxHeight to calculate height
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! It looks like `constraints.maxWidth` calculates to be `infinity`, and when I multiply any decimal by `infinity`, it equals the decimal value (e.g. `0.5 * constraints.maxWidth = 0.5`. So my `Container` is till just ~`1px` wide. 

Comment: the constraints.maxWidth gives the max midth your widget can have....try giving its parent a fixed width before using this...this should then calculate the width with the help of the percentage received....you can still give a width to its parent using same LayoutBuilder property.